# Forbidden error setting up a PHP app on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: php, macos, mac, snow-leopard

I have enabled Web Sharing in OS X 10.6 and now I can access `http://localhost/~myuser` from the browser.

Now I have copied this PHP app to my `~/Sites/the_app` folder, but when I want to access it in the browser I get a **Forbidden** error message:

> You don't have permission to access `/~myuser/the_app` on this server.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: Might get better answers on Apple.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `chmod 755` the folder and all of its parent folders.

Answer (score 0):

I know this KB document refers to 10.5, but it is possible that it might help you troubleshoot.  I had this same problem when I upgraded.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25038?viewlocale=en_US

To summarize, basically, you need a file named `myuser.conf` in the `/etc/apache2/users/` directory.

The contents of `myuser.conf` should contain the following:

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After that, set the permissions from the Terminal:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /etc/apache2/users/myuser.conf
```

Then restart Apache. (Uncheck/Recheck the Web Sharing box in System Preferences.)

And remember to change all instances of `myuser` to your *exact* username.

Answer (score 0):

By default, client versions of OS X have PHP disabled in the apache server. Because of this, the server will not load an `index.php` file unless you explicitly list it, and even then it will not run it.

To enable PHP, open the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file and find the area where it lists the modules (near the top). At the bottom of both lists, there will be load commands for the PHP module which are commented out. Remove the # from those lines, save the file, and restart web sharing. Now, the server will automatically recognize and run your `index.php` file.